# Error connecting to DB in /wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1538

Tags: database, wpdb

new in wordpress world.

My wordpress page keeps failing. It works from time to time, meaning refreshing sometimes offer the page, others it offers the `Error establishing a database connection` page.

Checking the `wp-content/debug.log` it says:

```
PHP Warning:  mysqli_real_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No address associated with hostname in /www/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1538
```

As far as I know, this file is a wordpress one so no one has touched it.

Any ideas from where it can come?
Any experience or tips on what to do?

Comment: Probably related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6275535/php-error-php-network-getaddresses-getaddrinfo-failed-while-getting-informat - sounds like a server config issue. I'd contact the host for assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Are you running on Ubuntu? Library `libc` was recently updated, and if you have `unattended-upgrades` enabled, that will be the cause. A restart of PHP-FPM, Apache, Nginx will solve it. Even better if you could reboot the entire server to be sure.

`libc` is the C implementation for Linux, and PHP runs on C.